# Does the compiler provide a address operator?

Tags: c++, compilation

"How many functions does compiler implement for us if we don't define one?", I think that there are only `4`:

- default ctor
- copy ctor
- assignment operator
- default destructor

But someone says that there are still one or more default functions: `address operator` and `address operator for const object`,is this right?

Comment: There are no address operator (i.e. some unary `operator &`) generated. And the answer to your question depends upon the C++ standard you are considering. *C++2011* might have added items to your list (w.r.t. C++03).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Do you mean the `move constructor`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the address operator is not implicitly overloaded for a class type. If you don't overload it, then the built-in operator can be applied to objects of that type, just as it can be applied to any object or function.

Note that in modern C++, you can add "move constructor" and "move-assignment operator" to your list.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Indeed, the current version of the language.